# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\arg((-1+i)^{2n})=\frac{1}{2}\pi$ and $\arg((1-\sqrt{3}i)^{n+1})=\frac{2}{3}\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I'm really iffy on complex numbers and I'd like to know if this is more or less correct. I first converted the numbers to trigonometric form:

$$-1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3}{4}\pi i} \\ 1-\sqrt{3}i=2e^{\frac{5}{3}\pi i}$$

Hence,

$$\arg((-1+i)^{2n})= \arg((\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3}{4}\pi i})^{2n})= n\arg(2e^{\frac{3}{2}\pi i}) - 2k\pi= \frac{3}{2}\pi n -2k\pi \\ 
\arg((1-\sqrt{3}i)^{n+1})= \arg((2e^{\frac{5}{3}\pi i})^{n+1}) = (n+1)\arg(2e^{\frac{5}{3}\pi i}) -2k'\pi=\frac{5}{3}\pi n - 2k'\pi$$

So we want to check that,

$$\begin{cases} \frac{3}{2}\pi n -2k\pi = \frac{1}{2} \pi \\ \frac{5}{3}\pi n - 2k'\pi = \frac{2}{3} \pi \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} 3n \equiv 1 \pmod4 \\ 5n+5 \equiv 2 \pmod 6 \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} n \equiv 3 \pmod4 \\ n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \end{cases}  $$

And the Chinese Remainder Theorem implies that this system of linear congruences has a unique solution (modulo $12$), namely,

$$n \equiv 3 \pmod {12}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, except I think you meant $\dfrac53\pi(n+1)$ where you wrote $\dfrac53\pi n.$

Comment: At first I thought you should have said $n\equiv3\pmod6$ instead of $n\equiv0\pmod3$, but then I realized that when also $3n\equiv1\pmod4$ then they are the same